# Array.IndexOf always returns -1

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net

This is my code.

```
Public Sub SomeFucntion(ByVal test As Short) 
    SomeOtherFucntion(MyArray)

    If Array.IndexOf(MyArray, test) <> -1
       //....
    End If
End Sub
```

test return value 10.

But i am getting `IndexOf` value as -1.
Inside `QuickWatch` in `VS 2005` when i put the value as 10 instead of test i am getting the correct `index`.

My array is single dimensional array which now has 2,5 and 10. Since its got 10 it should ideally return 2 as the index.

Comment: what is in your array?

Comment: edited my question to answer yours.

Comment: Show us the actual code. I haven't found any defects yet in IndexOf

Comment: That's not your code. test isn't set to a value, and the Array.IndexOf line is presumably missing an If statement....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be caused by the fact that your array contains **integers**, but the value you are looking for is a **short**. Consider the following example:

```
Dim myArray As Integer() = {5}
Dim value As Short = 5
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(myArray, value))  ' Prints -1
```

If the array contains integers, you need to convert your short into an integer first, for example, by using `CInt`:

```
Dim myArray As Integer() = {5}
Dim value As Short = 5
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(myArray, CInt(value)))  ' Prints 0
```

Edit: Note that the *declared type* has nothing to do with this. Let's declare the array as *Object*, since that's what you mentioned in your comment (note that the following example requires Option Strict Off, which is bad):

```
Dim myArray As Object = New Integer() {5}
Dim value As Object = 5S  ' Short literal
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(myArray, value))  ' still returns -1
Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(myArray, CInt(value)))  ' returns 0
```

Note: You can make that conversion implicit by declaring your function as `Public Sub SomeFunction(ByVal test As Integer)`.

Comment: Dim myArray As Object = Nothing is my declaration. as suggested earlier i also tried to change my test variable to object but it didnt help.

Comment: @user2322507: The declaration has nothing to do with it. You need to *convert* your short to an integer. You can do this explicitly (by using `CInt`) or implicitly (by declaring the parameter of your function as `Integer` instead of `Short`).

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim test As Short = 5

Dim MyArray() As Short = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3}
If Array.IndexOf(MyArray, test) <> -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Index Found.") 
End If
```

The above works. since test is declared as short, make sure MyArray is also declared as short.

Comment: my array definition is `Dim MyArray as Object = Nothing`

Comment: @user2322507: what do you *assign* to `MyArray`?

Comment: m assigning some integer values.

Comment: Then test also needs to be declared as object and again below works: Dim test As Object = 5 
Dim MyArray() As Object = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 3} 
If Array.IndexOf(MyArray, test) <> -1
 Then MessageBox.Show("Index Found.") 
End If

Comment: Are you saying the above code(AS IS) does not work for you? since it works for me.
If your code is different from the above please paste it here.

Comment: it kinda gave me a hint...+1